# Does Bardic Knowledge Encompass all other knowledge skills?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, bard, knowledge-check

If not,what Knowledge's would bardic Knowledge cover?

Answer (score 6):

Bardic knowledge is, effectively, about *stories*.

> A bard may make a special bardic knowledge check [...] to see whether he knows some relevant information about local notable people, legendary items, or noteworthy places.

So bardic knowledge can supply information you could know from any Knowledge skill, but it will only provide information that’s famous, interesting, funny, or so on—it will only provide information that makes for a good story. It will not provide technical details, boring treatises, or full family trees or organizational charts—unless those details form the climax of a story or punch-line of a joke.

Things that could be obtained with relatively low Knowledge skill checks thus may be unavailable to bardic knowledge, or else only available with a relatively high check. On the flip side, bardic knowledge covers a much broader array of fields to know something about.

Comment: So in short bardic knowledge is an all in one check, but at the same time it's something of a bootleg. At best you will probably just get some rumors that are worth looking into is that about accurate?

Comment: @Masakan You can get better than rumors; high checks can mean that you are quite certain about your results. It’s more the kinds of things that you can know this way that is different.

Comment: Just  a different way of getting potentially the same information, that's all i needed to know.

Comment: Think of it like this: Party is adventuring and is asked to find the Sword of Clan McGuffin. Any class could do a knowledge (nobility) or (history) or possibly (local) check to get specific, detailed information on that clan/sword, whereas the bard may recall The Ballad of Ewan McGuffin, which tells of a barbarian from that region with a sword that could cut through the strongest plot armor; depending on how high they score, that may even include the sword's final resting place. Not detailed info in most cases, but the kind of thing a storyteller might recall from a random story.